# Loading Images in Phaser and Node js

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Im am trying to load images in phaser with node js and i always get the same error

> :3000/assets/img/feet/idle/survivor-idle_0.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

if you know a way to get this to work please tell me. here is my code:

```
preload() {
    // Used for preloading assets into your scene
    //Idle feet image
    this.load.image('idleFeetFrame', '/assets/img/feet/idle/survivor-idle_0.png');
}
```

***(Updated from Comment)***
... is my server code:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.use(express.static('./public'));
console.clear();
console.log('\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m', 'Server started...\n');
const socket = require('socket.io');
const io = socket(server);
io.sockets.on('connection', handleConnection);

function handleConnection(socket) { console.log('Client: ' + socket.id + ' has connected.') }
```

Comment: What server are you using? how is it configured? what is the folder/file structure?...? Please share some more details?

Comment: I am using an express server. this is my server code:
`
const express = require('express');

const app = express();
const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000);

app.use(express.static('./public'));

console.clear();
console.log('\x1b[36m%s\x1b[0m', 'Server started...\n');

const socket = require('socket.io');

const io = socket(server);

io.sockets.on('connection', handleConnection);

function handleConnection(socket) {
    console.log('Client: ' + socket.id + ' has connected.')

}
`

Answer (score 0):

Since there are not any special routes configured in express, I assume all your files are in the folder `./public`.

In that case the file `survivor-idle_0.png` would have to be in the folder `./public/assets/img/feet/idle/survivor-idle_0.png` if you can't find it in that path, that is the problem *(check for typos, or extra folder like `src`)*.

As long as you are not using a bundler like webpack, parcel or so, just need to check your the `public` folder and fix the paths.
*If you are using a bundler, you will have to check the bundler configuration for errors.*

Comment: I checked my paths and could not find it thank you very much for your help have a good night. @winner_joiner